# files that have not been changed show up in unstaged list after git stash

Tags: git, git-stash

I have a repo with changes that I want to stash...so I do. After the stash a number of files show back up as being changed even though the only "change" is that all lines show as being removed and then re-added. I have NOT made these changes. To clarify, these files did not show up prior to the stash, as there were no changes made to them. Here's the most interesting part, after experimenting for many hours, I have found that I can copy the entire directory, perform a 'git checkout -- .' then a 'git status', and then the files that show up erroneously are gone. If I try the 'git checkout -- .' on the original repo, 'git status' shows that they are still there and nothing I do will get rid of them. Another thing to note, even after copying the repo, if I go a 'git status' first, prior to the 'git checkout -- .', it continue to erroneously show the files as being changed when, in fact, they have not been changed.

One more thing to note, I have read many posts about line endings, etc. This is NOT what's going on here. The files are identical, in every way.

Comment: This is likely a result in a change between line characters.  Git by default will store files using the linux method so when windows gets the file it modifies it to its own and git picks that up as a change. You'll want to do some reading on how to align git with your OS to resolve this. I unfortunately don't current;y have a concrete answer for how to resolve this.

Comment: I just noticed your line about it not being line endings, I would ask to you make doubly sure this is the case, when I ran into this issue I thought the same and I was mistaken.

Comment: Thanks Phaeze for the answer...unfortunately I have double checked this and it's not the problem. :-\

Comment: One thing I would try is to stage and commit those so called changes and see if they return.

Comment: That does remove them until the next `git stash` or switching branches causes them to return, but I don't want to introduce false history by committing just to work around this issue.

Comment: This seems like an issue that can be worked around...but that is super annoying. If anyone has seen this I would appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: How do you verify that files are truly unchanged?  Have you compared their sizes, control sums, or hex dumps?

Comment: @Basilevs that's a good point, I think I've seen something similar caused by a Unicode Bom: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark.

Comment: To clarify, I'm using WinMerge to compare the files.

Comment: @Kit, and merge tools do everything to hide BOM, EOL, etc differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One more thing to note, I have read many posts about line endings, etc. This is NOT what's going on here. The files are identical, in every way.

There is a scenario where the files can be **identical down to the last byte**, yet still be "different" according to `git status`. And yes, it usually does come down to line endings.

My best guess as to what is happening is that you are on a Windows machine, and that somewhere in your `.gitattributes` file you have a directive that tells git to perform line ending normalizations (via `* text=auto` or something similar). If this is indeed the case, then when you checkout a file its LFs are converted to CRLFs, and when you commit a file its CRLFs are converted to LFs.

If so, what is most likely happening is that the repository version of the files in question somehow have CRLFs in them. When you check them out, the working copies would of course also have those CRLFs. Now here's the rub: when doing a `git status`, `git diff`, etc. git compares what is in the repo/index not to what is actually in your working directory, but to what *would* be committed after line ending normalization is done, i.e. with the CRLFs replaced by LFs. In this case, git sees that what is in the index/repo has CRLFs, and what you *would* commit only has LFs, and thus there is a difference.

To see if this is the case, run the following commands:

```
git hash-object path/to/your/file
git hash-object --no-filter path/to/your/file
git ls-files -s path/to/your/file
```

The first command will show you the hash of what *would* be committed. The second command shows you the hash of what is actually in your working directory. The third command shows you the hash of what is in the index. If the first and second hashes are different, and the second and third hashes are the same, you are almost definitely in the situation I have described.

So the question is, how to get out of it? One simple way is to simply add/commit the "changes". This will have the effect of putting LFs in the repository copy, solving the problem going forward. If everyone using the repository is on Windows, however, there is really no need for the line normalizations anyway. You can disable them by putting `* -text` in your `.gitattributes` file (and removing any lines below it that sets the type of a file to text). That's the option I chose when I ran into this problem, as I'm not a fan of my version control system changing the contents of my files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I do have `* text=auto` in my `.gitattributes` file but I was under the impression that this left endings "as-is" which is what I selected when I installed git on my windows box. This is the behavior I would like...to leave endings "as-is" and not change them. The next time this happens, I'll run the commands you posted and see if it exposes the issue.